# Button to create record based on current records data

Tags: custom-button, insert, record

I have a custom Invoice object on my organisation with multiple custom fields (prices, Due date, ...) and also a `Credit Note` checkbox to specify if it is a an invoice or a credit note.

I would like a button on my record page to generate the credit note for this invoice with all the same values for its fields except for `Credit note` that has  to be checked.

I do not find a real answer to my questions by reading those:

- https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gwhCAAQ
- http://kell.screenstepslive.com/s/knowledgebase/m/16056/l/163679-how-to-create-a-button-that-auto-fills-in-field-on-a-new-record

Is there a way to call, by clicking the button, an APEX class I created to generate it based on the current invoice ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can call apex class on Button click from page layout. 
Following is the reference-
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook.meta/workbook/button_1.htm

Comment: Thank you. Did not found the documentation page.

Comment: The link that i have shared is best suitable for your requirement.

Comment: I can not use the new custom button on my lightning experience layout.

Comment: Custom Javascript and URL buttons aren't supported in lightning experience, see [link](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000Zf7vAAC)

Comment: Also this [link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/lex_migrate_customizations.htm) under the "Custom Buttons" header